# Secure elmah with ASp.NET security but only to some users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, elmah, security

HI, I am developing a ASP.NET App and I want to add elmah. The problem I have is the the users login to the site and the only way I found to secure elmah is to authenticate users, not a specific user.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2 and NET 4.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to restrict the elmah.axd (assuming you're using the handler) to a specific user role.  Not just all authenticated users.

```
<!-- Deny unauthenticated users to see the elmah.axd -->
<location path="admin/elmah.axd">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Admins" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Phil Haack has a good [write up](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/07/24/securely-implement-elmah-for-plug-and-play-error-logging.aspx) on the subject.

Comment: I Williams try it and let you know. I am not using asp.net autorización but a custom security model, i Williams let you know how it was